# Ошибка компиляции, thread C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, ооп

```
class Buff {
public:
    void use(Mob& mob_passive) {
        ::std::thread threading{&Buff::apply_buff, this, mob_passive}; // Пробовал с this и без него
        threading.detach();
    }

    void apply_buff(Mob& mob_passive) {
        use_all_buffs(mob_passive);
        Sleep(seconds * 1000);
        complete(mob_passive);

        delete this;
    }
....
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> C2672 "std::invoke": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
>   - xthread:238
>
> C2893 Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "unknown-type
>   std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()" - xthread:237

Comment: Попробуйте в `::std::thread threading{&Buff::apply_buff, this, mob_passive};` заменить фигурные скобки на круглые.

Comment: @V-Mor , пробовал... не помогает...

Comment: Воспроизвёл Ваш код. Действительно любопытная ошибка. У меня есть схожий код, который работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал рабочий код из Вашего, заменив `mob_passive` на `std::ref(mob_passive)` в третьем аргументе конструктора:

```cpp
class Buff {
public:
    void use(Mob& mob_passive) {
        ::std::thread threading{&Buff::apply_buff, this, std::ref(mob_passive)}; // Пробовал с this и без него
        threading.detach();
    }

    void apply_buff(Mob& mob_passive) {
        use_all_buffs(mob_passive);
        Sleep(seconds * 1000);
        complete(mob_passive);

        delete this;
    }
....
```

По всей видимости, проблема была в том, что ссылка автоматически разыменовывается везде, где Вы её используете. Следовательно в метод `apply_buff` передавалось значение типа `Mob` вместо `Mob&`. В `std` есть функция для получения ссылки из значения – `ref`, которую можно использовать для передачи ссылки в качестве аргумента функции.

P.S. При попытке воспроизвести Ваш код, уже после запуска программы, она крашнулась из-за `delete this;`. Не уверен, что это хорошо.

Comment: а чем отличается ваш код от того, что есть в вопросе?

Comment: Будьте внимательнее. Третьим аргументом в конструкторе стоит `std::ref(mob_passive)` вместо `mob_passive`.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда в ответе не нужно выложите весь код, а  только эту часть: "Заменить  ... на ... " . Так лучше и понятнее для читателей, и ответ будет  конкретней

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я выложил весь код, чтобы у автора вопроса сразу был рабочий вариант и не возникло проблем из-за возможный синтаксических упущений при замене. Но в том, что стоит описать, что именно было изменено, Вы правы. Сейчас добавлю.